# Ehcache logging level

Tags: java, ehcache, java.util.logging

I find a lot of examples of how to change Ehcache logging level for slf4j and logback ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10705107/1429387), [2](https://www.mkyong.com/ehcache/ehcache-logging-example/)). But how to do the same if my application uses [JUL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) for logging?

logging.properties

```bash
.level=INFO

# Handlers
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# this has no visible effect on logging:
net.sf.ehcache=ALL
```

dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unless you're working with a legacy project, It's never a good idea to use JUL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the logging level by adding `.level` for the property in the logging properties file. Can be applied to packages as well as individual classes/loggers.

```
# This should have a bigger effect
net.sf.ehcache.level=ALL
```

Now this will allow for logging all levels for `net.sf.ehcache`. Note, that your log handler must also permit logging on that level, so if you need to log more detailed than `INFO` for a handler you must change that detail level as well. For instance:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

To combine all of this for you logging properties example like this:

```
.level=INFO

# Handlers
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

net.sf.ehcache.level=ALL
```

The above will log ehcache logging for all levels in your `ConsoleHandler` and up to `INFO` for all other loggers/classes/packages. For `FileHandler` everything is logged up to `INFO` level only.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is helpful. But I noticed that I need additionally to lower logging level of ConsoleHandler or FileHandler, otherwise messages below INFO are not displayed in log. For example: `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL`

Comment: Yeah, I thought you knew that. I added additional explanations in the answer.